# How to hide some dots in a matplotlib scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
y = np.random.rand(100)
plt.scatter(list(range(100)), y)
```

The commend above will draw a scatter with matplotlib.

Suppose I want to hide the points whose values are less than 0.5. At the same time, I should remain the x-axis unchanged. How should I do it?

Comment: Don't plot the dots you don't want to plot, specify the xlim as you want them. As simple as that. What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: I didn't get it, could you show me the code? @Julien

Comment: nope this is not how SO works, try it yourself first.

Comment: @Julien supose x=[0,1,2,3,4], y=[0.6, 0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.9]. I just want to hide the 0.3 point and keep the other points unchanged.

Comment: @Julien I think you misunderstood my question. I have (0,0.6), (1, 0.5), (2, 0.3), (3, 0.8), (4, 0.9) these five points. And I want to hide (2, 0.3) and keep the others unchanged. If using your method, I will get (0,0.6), (1, 0.5), (2, 0.8), (3, 0.9). This is not I wanted.

Comment: @Phil Save the current x limits, clear the axes, call `scatter` with the filtered data, restore the x limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a mask that selects only those points that satisfy `y > 0.5`:

```
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
mask = y > 0.5
plt.scatter(x[mask], y[mask])
```

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, I would use a `for` loop and create a new variable `y1` and replace all of the values in y that are less than 0.5 with `NaN` then graph `y1`. So from this (altered the numpy function to give you some negative figures as well)

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    y = np.random.randint(low=-100,high=100, size=100)
    plt.scatter(list(range(0,len(y))), y)
    plt.show()
```

to this:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    y = np.random.randint(low=-100,high=100, size=100)
    y1 = []
    for i in y:
        if i < 0.5:
            i = 'NaN'
        y1.append(i)

    plt.scatter(list(range(0,len(y1))), y1)
    plt.show()
```

you can see the result by plotting both

```
    plt.scatter(list(range(0,len(y))), y)
    plt.scatter(list(range(0,len(y))), y1)
```

It's probably not the *best* answer, but it does the job.

Comment: Thanks so much! It really worked. I found None can also hide the point.

Comment: the solution by @user8153 below is more elegant. Which one is more helpful probably depends on whether you want to do any further calculations on your truncated dataset. If you do, then this might be a better solution, but for simply plotting, the other version seems better